# Django navlink URL are not working and receiving no error

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iOGe.png)

I have used Django URL on the nav link and for some reason unable to click on them there is no error returning just nothing is happening. And I am working in the core project directory there has been no app created till now.

```
        <nav>
            <a href={% url 'home_page' %}>
                <img src={% static "assets/images/templatemo-eduwell.png" %} alt="EduWellTemplate">
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href={% url 'home_page' %}>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href={% url 'services' %}>Services</a></li>
                <li><a href={% url 'contact_us' %}>Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href={% url 'home_page' %}>Login</a></li>
                <li><a href={% url 'home_page' %}>Buy now</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a>
                <span>Menu</span>
            </a>
            <!-- ***** Menu End ***** -->
        </nav>
```

```
           urlpatterns = [
                path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                path('', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
                path('about-us/', views.about_us, name='about_us'),
                path('contact-us/', views.contact_us, name='contact_us'),
                path('services/', views.our_services, name='services')
            ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve] and describe the behavior you see as well as how it differs from what you want. Once you provide these additional details we will try to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Did some changes to the post please check again if it's a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The changes you made are superficial. Please read the link I gave in the previous comment and follow it's suggestions.

Comment: Additionally, you should use `"` around `href` attribute, like this: `<a href="{% url 'home_page' %}">`

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone thanks for helping but the problem was not in HTML or Django due to the nature of the problem I thought it was the error from either HTML or Django it turns out the error was in CSS file precisely there was class which made me unable to click on the links

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).